# How to copy 'type' information into an 'instance' in mongo aggregation and Lookup... and keep the original list?

Tags: mongodb, types, aggregate, instance, lookup

During a mongo aggregation I am trying to copy over type information onto an 'instance'... and return the original object structure intact.

Some clarification: An instance means a patient has a record on the indicating they have a medication of 'Asprin'. It only contains the medicationId and the start and stop date. Not the entire medication information. In a different collection are all the types of medications that are possible. We call one former the instance and the later the type.

What I am trying to do is when we retrieve the patient, we of course also return all the medications on that patient. But I then need to take the 5 medications on the patient 'copy' over the name and description from the type. The final result would be the entire patient record, including medications, *with the addition* of the medication name and description from the type.

In code I would just loop over each medication and then query the type using the medication Id and set the name. This should be very easy to do in the DB.

Trying to do this in the db verses code.

Example: I have a collection of medication types. Each type has a name, id and dosage..etc.

`

```
db.medications.insert([
                {"medicationId": "1","Name": "Asprin",... },
                {"medicationId": "2","Name": "Tylenol", ... }]);
```

`

And on a patient record the patient has a list of medications.
`db.patients.insert([{
            "firstName": "patient1",
            "medications": [
                {"medicationId":"1", ... },
                {"medicationId":"2", ... },
            ]
        }`

and what I am trying to do is simply populate the name on each 'instance' of the medication on the patient by matching the medicationId in the types collection.

This is a very common pattern for us where we always store a lot of information on the type but the instance is really tight. But we want to show type information in some cases (such as the name and description) when we show a patient record.

I can't figure how to do a set as part of the lookup pipeline. I can only seem to return the list of medications that are matching by medication Id but then I loose the original set.

I tried the below but it just replaces the medication with the one from the type collection.

`{ $lookup:
            {
                from: "medications",
                localField: "medications.medicationId",
                foreignField: "medicationId",
                as: "medications"
            },
        })`

I would be happy if they were just merged.. I tried that but merge is somehow not allowed in a lookup pipeline?  The good news is the above leaves the original 'patient' record intact, which is what I want, but now I just need to merge the two somehow

Comment: Not getting it completely. Whats instance here? Can you post expected output for more clarification?

Comment: Sorry I added more detail. Appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have the following data in DB:

```
medications:
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d4fc7c8a412da1f166525e5"),
        "medicationId" : "1",
        "Name" : "Asprin"
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d4fc7c8a412da1f166525e6"),
        "medicationId" : "2",
        "Name" : "Tylenol"
    }

patients:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4fc7eaa412da1f166525e7"),
    "firstName" : "patient1",
    "medications" : [
        {
            "medicationId" : "1"
        },
        {
            "medicationId" : "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.patients.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind:"$medications"
    },
    {
        $lookup:{
            "from":"medications",
            "localField":"medications.medicationId",
            "foreignField":"medicationId",
            "as":"medicationsLookup"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:{
            "path":"$medicationsLookup",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":true
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields:{
            "medications.Name":"$medicationsLookup.Name"
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":"$_id",
            "firstName":{
                $first:"$firstName"
            },
            "medications":{
                $push:"$medications"
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4fc7eaa412da1f166525e7"),
    "firstName" : "patient1",
    "medications" : [
        {
            "medicationId" : "1",
            "Name" : "Asprin"
        },
        {
            "medicationId" : "2",
            "Name" : "Tylenol"
        }
    ]
}
```

*Note: both collections are still intact*

***Aggregation stages details:***

- Stage I: Unwinds the medications array
- Stage II: Lookup each medication Id from the array with medication Id present in 'medications' collection
- Stage III: Add new field 'Name' in the pipeline
- Stage IV: Group back data on the basis of the object ID

Comment: This answered the question. So what you did was unwind the original list of medications, get all the matches from the types, unwind those preserving the empty (so if there is no med found it just unwinds but has no med) and then you add the field over from the unpacked med type. Very nice.. and thank you!

Comment: Is there any performance issue with all the unpacking? if the patient record is large, it will effectively duplicate that data many times depending on if there are a lot of medications. This did solve the use case so for sure this will work for now, just wondering if there was any solution to solve it without duplicating the original root patient record so many times and then grouping it back down?